# Microsoft AX 2009/Axapta, prompt before compile

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

Is there a way to have AX/Axapta, prompt **before** compiling?

I have accidentally clicked compile for the entire app several times now, and since it takes 30-60 minutes, if I could add a prompt prior, it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop the compile by pressing Ctrl-Break.

You could add a prompt to the class method `ClassFactory.createCompilerOutput`. Calling the compiler from the menu, or from the AOT both trigger that method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually it does have a prompt in `\Classes\SysCompileAll\prompt`.

You may consider removing it from the menu. Or make yet another "Are you sure" prompt.

Comment: if I open the AOT, then click Compile, I get no prompt.